# Laser color, does it depend on the reference system of the beholder?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, speed-of-light

Like the question says. Let's say we emit red light (we see it as red) from a laser device. Does the color of the laser depends on the speed of the beholder or not?
I feel that, as the speed of light doesn't depend on the reference system of the observer, it will the same.
Am I right or not?

Comment: Yes, ala redshift or blueshift doppler effect.

Comment: Doppler effect is for sound. I don't think it can be applied for light.  That's what this question is about.

Comment: It exists for light too. After all, you can't *blue*shift or *red*shift sound.

Comment: Doppler shift is applicable to *all* waves; sound, light, gravity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When once speaks of the color of light, there is a implicit reference frame. A plane wave (in the $z$-direction) takes the form:

$$ E(x,y,z,t) = E_0e^{i(kz-\omega t)}=E_0e^{i\phi(z, t)}$$

where

$$\phi(z,t)=kz-\omega t$$

is the phase.

If we Lorentz transform that with a boost along $z$ (by inverse transforming the primed coordinates):

$$ t = \gamma(t'+\frac{vz'}{c^2})$$
$$ z = \gamma(z'+v't)$$

the transformed phase is:

$$\phi'(z',t')=k\gamma(z+vt)-\omega\gamma(t+\frac{vz}{c^2})$$

With:

$$ \gamma \equiv \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{(1-\frac v c)(1+\frac v c)}}$$

and

$$ \omega = kc$$

we get

$$\phi'(z',t') =k'z'-\omega't'=\phi(z,t)$$

where

$$k'=f_Dk$$
$$\omega'=f_D\omega$$

with:

$$ f_D = \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac v c}{1+\frac v c}}$$

is the well known Doppler factor.

So the phase of a plane wave is a Lorentz invariant: all reference frames agree on it, but the wavelength and frequency can be any non-zero number which depends entirely on the observer's reference frame.

(The field strength also transforms in manner that keeps the average number of photons invariant...should you go that route.).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the observed color depends on the reference system of the observer, due to the [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect).